# How to remove 'orphan' tables in SpatiaLite database

Tags: qgis, spatialite, spatialite-gui

I have a SpatiaLite (4.3) database created in QGIS that I have modified numerous times using the SpatiaLite-GUI. I've realized today that when I add a table within QGIS from that DB, the selection dialog lists several tables that have been deleted long ago.

I can find references to the deleted tables with the following queries:

```
select * from vector_layers
select * from geometry_columns
```

I know that I can simply save the remaining tables into a new DB, but I'm wondering if there is some sort of bookkeeping query to clean up a database.